# laravel CRUD Radio Button is not checked when trying to edit

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel CRUD, I am able or update data from the radio button, but when I click on edit radio button is not checked based upon value in the database.
I have two radio buttons (single and married) both radio buttons are unchecked when I click on edit. what I want is if database value is married radio button married should be checked. 
here is my code:

**view:**

```
<lable>Single</lable>
<input type="radio" name="sm" value="single"  @if(@$category->sm == "single") checked @endif>
<lable>Married</lable>
<input type="radio" name="sm" value="married"  @if(@$category->sm == "married") checked @endif>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
   $category->sm = $request->sm;   
      return back()->with('message','Record Successfully Updated!');
}
```

Comment: you aren't passing the data correctly - please paste controller code for the edit method

Comment: your edit method should be used to show the edit view, your update method should be used to store the request from the edit page - as you are trying to work with the edit view, we will need to see the code for the edit method

Comment: @CodeBoyCode Edit:
  public function edit(Category $category)
    {
         $categories = Category::where('id','!=',$category->id);
         return view('admin.categories.create',['categories' => $categories, 'category'=>$category]);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using blade

```
<input type="radio" name="sm" value="single"  {{ $category->sm == "single" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

This is saying:

if statement ? (is true) do this 'checked' else '' (empty string)

your code:

```
<label>Single</label>
<input type="radio" name="sm" value="single" {{ $category->sm == "single" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
<label>Married</label>
<input type="radio" name="sm" value="married" {{ $category->sm == "married" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Edit: You also spelt `<label>` incorrectly

edit2:

After looking at your controller code, you will need to do something like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
     $category = Category::findOrFail($id);

     return view('admin.categories.create',['category'=>$category]);
}
```

This should allow you to access the properties for `$category->sm` within your view

Comment: and you can do the same with the married one aswell

<input type="radio" name="sm" value="married"  {{ $category->sm == "married" ?  'checked' : '' }}>

Comment: can you please tell me where {{ is ending? .
i tried:  <input type="radio" name="sm" value="single"  {{$category->sm == "single" ? 'checked' : ''}} >
Error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: i tried:  <input type="radio" name="sm" value="married" {{ $category->sm == "married" ? 'checked' : '' }}> 
Result: both buttons are still unchecked.

Comment: copied exact your code but still both are unchecked, please help

Comment: you will need to post all of your view and controller code, this should work if everything is being passed correctly

Comment: are you doing these within a forloop?

Comment: please see updated code, your edit method was incorrect

Comment: i replaced edit controller code and got this error: Undefined variable: id

Comment: can you post your web route list - (i had to guess the variable name due to not seeing the web routes)

Comment: yes i pasted your code, both radio buttons are still unchecked.

Comment: i am getting all other values in my text box when i click on edit, only radio buttons are not checked.

Comment: what do you get if you add {{ $category }} to your view?

Comment: this: {"id":14,"SM":"married","TF":"Non M","title":"kjlkjlk","description":"jkljlkjkl","slug":"kjlkjlk","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2019-02-22 13:03:47","updated_at":"2019-02-22 15:24:50"}

Comment: That’s why you should be calling $category->SM

Comment: Rather than $category->sm

Comment: SOLVED: sm should be SM, Thankyou so much.

Comment: you are genius, keep it up.

Comment: no worries man - sorry it was long winded! thanks for stinking with it, glad you got it sorted, all of your code was really good, so keep going man - this was a minor thing, keep it up!